# iOS - In which queue selectors run on by default?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, handler, uialertcontroller

Suppose, I am presenting an `UIAlertController`, say `myAlert`, from main tread. `myAlert` has a action, `defaultAction`. I wonder if `defaultAction`s handler by default runs on main queue or not. In other words, I wonder if there are some UI related operation inside `doStuff` in below code, am I required to wrap these UI tasks with main queue or it is guaranteed to run in main queue by OS?

```
UIAlertController* myAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                               message:@"This is an alert."
                               preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
      doStuff() // should I wrap doStuff in main queue, if doStuff has ui operations?
   }
];

[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are actually asking if it runs on the main queue, not if it is thread safe.

An object is "thread safe" if it can be accessed/modified from multiple threads without issue.

The answer to your question is that the action closure will run on the main queue as it results from a user interaction, so you do not need to explicitly dispatch UI updates onto the main queue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the question title. I also assume something like you said, `action closure will run on the main queue as it results from a user interaction`. I was wondering if there is any documentation or clue on these.

Comment: It may be documented somewhere, but it is just common sense; You don't need to dispatch UI code in an `@IBAction` onto the main queue because the main queue is the queue that is responsible for UI

Comment: @Paulw11This is absolutely not common sense and Apple has a history of closures UI related that are never guaranteed (and sometimes do not) callback on the main thread. Please link out documentation and tests if there is proof to back this claim.

Comment: Please show me a case where user interaction with a UIControl does not cause the action handler to be run on the mai queue.

Comment: @Paulw11 UIAltertController actions were known to have a side effect of running on a separate thread randomly on callbacks when first launched. Regardless, unless you can provide documentation proving all callbacks for UI components run on the main thread, then the behavior is undefined. Even if you wrote a test to prove that that is true for a specified version of iOS, it’s still undefined when it’s undocumented. You’re now making an assumption, which is extremely dangerous. A true statement could be: “in my experience, I have not seem a UI related callback come back on a background thread“.